# How to filter Logging in ASP MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc-3, visual-studio-2010

I am developing an ASP .Net MVC 3 application using C# and SQL Server 2005.
I want to customize my interface depending on the type of user logged.
I was following 
[this tuto](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vs2010trainingcourse_aspnetmvc3customactionfilters_topic2)
in the microsoft site and i am stuck when he use ActionLog instance in the filter class (ActionLogFilterAttribute).
Infact, this class is declared in 'StoreDB.designer.cs' class which i don't have because i created my project using the 'code first' method of Entity Framework.
I have only this class for the context :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
namespace MvcApplication2.Models
{
    public class GammeContext : DbContext
    {
        public GammeContext()
        {
          Database.SetInitializer(new DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<GammeContext>());
        }

        public DbSet<Account> Accounts { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Ns_AFaire> Ns_AFaires { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Famille> Familles { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Fonction> Fonctions { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Fonction_Poste> Fonction_Postes { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Gamme> Gammes { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Historique> Historiques { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Ligne> Lignes { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Phase> Phases { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Poste> Postes { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Produit> Produits { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Profile_Ga> Profil_Gas { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Sous_Famille> Sous_Familles { get; set; }
        public DbSet<UF> UFs { get; set; }
        public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Num_Serie> Num_Series { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Conventions.PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
        }
    }
}
```

and this is the filter class that i created :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using MvcApplication2.Models;

namespace MvcApplication2.Filters
{
    public class ActionLogFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute, IActionFilter
    {
        public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
        {
            GammeContext db = new GammeContext();
            ActionLog log = new ActionLog()
            {
                Controller = filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ControllerDescriptor.ControllerName,
                Action = filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ActionName,
                IP = filterContext.HttpContext.Request.UserHostAddress,
                DateTime = filterContext.HttpContext.Timestamp
            };
            db.AddToActionLogs(log);
            db.SaveChanges();
            base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
        }
    }
}
```

So, is there any solution ??

Answer (score 0):

The ActionLog instance he is using is the Enitity that is related to his ActionLog table.

What you need to do is to add your own ActionLog entity - that is all :)

Comment: You add model and mapper classes, and add a `public DbSet<ActionLog> ActionLogs { get; set; }` to your GammeContext.